# Slow query execution in Firebird

Tags: sql, performance, firebird

My executed SQL query is as follow :

```
update elements E
    set E.END_I = (select n.node_num
                   from nodes N 
                   where abs(E.X_I - N.XI) < 0.001 and
                         abs(E.Y_I - N.YI) < 0.001 and
                         abs(E.Z_I - N.ZI) < 0.001
                  )
```

It takes about 24 secs to complete, I read about firebird troubleshooting  [Why is my database query slow?](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq13/) It instructs to create indices for the related fields in table and I've added the decreasing/increasing indices for the XI, YI, ZI fields in both of the Nodes and Elements tables. But still the performance is very slow, there 6677 rows in database and I'm using the FlameRobin as SQL editor.

Interesting thing is: As depicted in Firebird troubleshooting guide having

> If you see a NATURAL plan going against a big table, you've found the
>   problem

this error is described as bad case and source of slow down, recommended solution is, create decreasing indices for related fields. But in my case even after defining  the indices it seems that I'm still suffering from that PLAN (N NATURAL), PLAN (E NATURAL) which is reported in Flamerobin output as shown below.

How am I supposed to eliminate that?

```
Preparing query: update elements E set E.END_I = (select n.node_num from nodes N 
where abs(E.X_I-N.XI)<0.001 and abs(E.Y_I - N.YI)<0.001 and abs(E.Z_I-N.ZI)<0.001 )
Prepare time: 0.004s
PLAN (N NATURAL)
PLAN (E NATURAL)

Executing...
Done.
108818273 fetches, 79227 marks, 4050 reads, 9380 writes.
0 inserts, 6677 updates, 0 deletes, 0 index, 14549183 seq.
Delta memory: 212 bytes.
ELEMENTS: 6677 updates. 
6677 rows affected directly.
Total execution time: 24.038s
Script execution finished.

CREATE DESCENDING INDEX IDX_ELEMENTS1 ON ELEMENTS (Z_I);
CREATE DESCENDING INDEX IDX_XI ON ELEMENTS (X_I);
CREATE DESCENDING INDEX IDX_YI ON ELEMENTS (Y_I);
GRANT DELETE, INSERT, REFERENCES, SELECT, UPDATE
 ON ELEMENTS TO  SYSDBA WITH GRANT OPTION;

CREATE DESCENDING INDEX IDX_NODES1_XI ON NODES (XI);
CREATE DESCENDING INDEX IDX_NODES1_YI ON NODES (YI);
CREATE DESCENDING INDEX IDX_NODES1_ZI ON NODES (ZI);
GRANT DELETE, INSERT, REFERENCES, SELECT, UPDATE
 ON NODES TO  SYSDBA WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Comment: I don't think there is a simple way to improve the performance of your query.  You might consider some sort of GIS extension.

Comment: The definition of said indexes should be included.

Comment: Please find the definitions at the problem description.

Comment: So the definitons are right ?

Comment: For a condition like `abs(E.X_I - N.XI) < 0.001` the index cannot be used.

Comment: Could you describe the data in these columns. What are possible values, ranges and precision? Maybe the current datatype is wrong, and you'd be better of with a `NUMERIC` with a restricted scale.

Comment: data types is double precision,I know that its flawed type for comparison, from your previous posts, the best matching datatype in flamerobin was float(numeric always was offering Integer which is not applicable in my case, also the decimal), so I thought that float or double precision wouldn't matter and I left it intact.

Comment: But what are some of the values, if for example a precision of 3 decimals is sufficient a `NUMERIC(18,3)` or `DECIMAL(18,3)` (or maybe even `NUMERIC(5, 3)`) could be sufficient and allow for exact comparisons. Also, have you tried `E.X_I BETWEEN N.XI - 0.001 AND N.XI + 0.001`?

Comment: I believe you can create indexes on computed columns: http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd20-create-index.html
You might then want to create indexes for the expressions (abs(...)) and try the same statement again.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I totally misunderstand you and misinterpreted the numeric usage, so now that I know it, I 'll try to testify it carefully, since I don't want to spoil anything in table structure. BTW `between` is also lags in performance. @Jakub Kania's answer yield  best performance up to now as 3~6 sec at utmost, problem is literally `abs` function.

Comment: @RonDeijkers You **cannot** create a computed index for this expression, because the columns are not from the same table

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Ah yeah I see now. I didn't look carefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is slowed down by the `abs()` function as the index on bare column doesn't work with expressions.
Try changing the query to at least give the db a chance to use an index

```
update elements E
    set E.END_I = (select n.node_num
                   from nodes N 
                   where N.XI < E.X_I + 0.001 AND N.XI > E.X_I - 0.001
                   AND N.YI < E.Y_I + 0.001 AND N.YI > E.Y_I - 0.001
                   AND N.ZI < E.Z_I + 0.001 AND N.ZI > E.Z_I - 0.001
                  )
```

Comment: Additions and subtractions will disable index as well.

Comment: @AndrejKirejeŭ: but that statement could possibly use the indexes defined on the `nodes` table

Comment: Also I want say that in this case we don't need three indexes. We need one index on three columns to make it work. Like this `create index on nodes(XI, YI, ZI)`. Also we don't  need indexes on `elements` table at all.

Answer (score 0):

Create indices on columns X_I, Y_I, Z_I, then run statement:

```
MERGE INTO elements dst
   USING (
    SELECT e.x_i, e.y_i, e.z_i, n.node_num
    FROM nodes N JOIN elements E ON 
      abs(E.X_I - N.XI) < 0.001 and
      abs(E.Y_I - N.YI) < 0.001 and
      abs(E.Z_I - N.ZI) < 0.001
   ) src
ON dst.X_I = src.X_I AND dst.Y_I = src.Y_I AND dst.Z_I = src.Z_I
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET dst.END_I = src.NODE_NUM
```

As mentioned in the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/34656659/55350 you could get rid of ABS functions and create indices on columns XI, YI, ZI of N table to further speed up a process.

Comment: Indices are already there, I tried your query it is still computing since you post the answer, that really is slower than the original one. I think it freezed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this could help:

1) Create a cartesian product between tables, calculating X, Y and Z.

2) Filter just desired records.

3) Update elements records with node_num value.

```
execute block
as
declare variable key integer; -- primary key type
declare variable node_num integer; -- node_num type
begin
  for
    select
      key,
      node_num
    from (
      select
        E.key, -- primary key name
        N.node_num,
        abs(E.X_I - N.XI) as X,
        abs(E.Y_I - N.YI) as Y,
        abs(E.Z_I - N.ZI) as Z
      from elements E, nodes N)
    where (X < 0.001)
      and (Y < 0.001)
      and (Z < 0.001)
    into
      :key,
      :node_num
  do
  begin
    update elements set
      END_ID = :node_num
    where elements.key = :key; -- primary key name
  end
end
```